# How to generate hard subset sum instances

Tags: hardness-assumptions, knapsack

A subset sum problem can be defined as:

- Given a set of integers $S$
- A target integer $x$
- Find some subset of elements $s \in S$ such that $\sum_0^{n}s_i = x$

The "density" of a subset sum problem is defined as: $\text{density} = \frac{k}{\operatorname{log}(\operatorname{max}(S))}$

Where $k$ is the number of elements in the set $S$ and $\operatorname{log}(\operatorname{max}(S))$ is the size of the largest element in the set.

Subset sum problems of density $\lt 0.9408$ [can be solved in polynomial time](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3cbf/017823e250f15c59701faac1130ff49c8947.pdf).

I would like to know:

- How can we generate hard instances of the subset sum problem that are not solvable in polynomial time, or more specifically, require exponential time to solve?

  - Is it sufficient to use any size set and with elements such that $\text{density} = 1$? Assume that all set elements are uniformly random and of size $\operatorname{log}(\operatorname{max}(S))$
  - Is a higher density necessarily more difficult?
- Supposing we can generate problems that require exponential time to solve, what parameter is the problem exponential in?

  - A set of size $8$ with $8$-bit elements has a density of $1$, and so does a set of size $256$ with $256$-bit elements, so if $\text{density} = 1$ is the requirement for hardness then it wouldn't make sense for the running time to be exponential in the density parameter.

Comment: Single integral for area, double integral for volume, and triple integral for density is my understanding

Comment: Subset sums instances of density near 1 only have known exponential-time algorithms to solve them, the best of which is [Becker-Coron-Joux](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/474) at $\tilde{O}(2^{0.291n})$ complexity. The complexity is exponential on the dimension $n$, i.e., the number of elements being added.

Comment: I wonder if its possible to create a family algorithms such that for instances with a fixed density less than 1 there exists a polynomial time algorithm but as the density approaches 1 the exponent on this algorithm grows without bound. That would be kind of cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we generate hard instances of the subset sum problem that are not solvable in polynomial time, or more specifically, require exponential time to solve?
>
> Is it sufficient to use any size set and with elements such that $\text{density}=1$? Assume that all set elements are uniformly random and of size $\operatorname{log}(\operatorname{max}(S))$
>
> Supposing we can generate problems that require exponential time to solve, what parameter is the problem exponential in?

### Conditions and Parameters

[The hardest instances have](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Enaor/PAPERS/subset.pdf) $\text{density} = 1$.

An instance of the problem with $\text{density} = 1$ will require time [exponential in the number of elements that are summed together](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58220/how-to-generate-hard-subset-sum-instances#comment127948_58220).

To generate hard instances of the problem, ensure that:

- The number of elements in the set $k$ is equal to the the size of the largest element in the set (in bits)
- All elements in the set are approximately that size (you can't have a single element of size $\operatorname{log}(k)$ and the rest of the elements small).
- Each instance should sum ($k / 2)$ of the elements of the set together.

  - If you were to sum $k - 1$ elements of the set together, then you could solve an easier problem (namely: subtract elements from the sum of the entire set until you find which one(s) isn't a member of the target subset)

### Cost

Basically, you need $k$ uniformly random elements of size $\operatorname{log}(k)$ for a hard instance of the problem. This implies that a hard instance of the problem will require $O(k^2)$ space.

There is [a quantum attack](https://cr.yp.to/qsubsetsum/qsubsetsum-20130407.pdf) against the subset sum problem that runs in time $O((0.241... + O(1)) * n)$, which we will round to $O(.25 * n)$ to make the following math more convenient:

Assuming the complexity of the quantum attack cited above using the conditions laid out above, the computational cost to solve a subset sum problem of size $k$ is $O(2^{k / 8})$.

- To generate instances of the problem that require approximately $O(2^{128})$ computational cost against a quantum adversary, set $k = 1024$.

  - This will use $1024^2 = 1048576$ bits of space.

> Is a higher density necessarily more difficult?

No, instances of the problem with $\text{density} > 1$ are more easily solved.